# Keyboard backlight in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-backlight

Where is the keyboard backlight option in Ubuntu 22.04? It was in the power section in settings in previous versions.

After installing `sudo apt install brightnessctl` it is not showing anything except device not found.

Comment: It depends on hardware and doesn't work on all devices.

Answer (score 5):

The command line tool worked on my Asus laptop.

- Open a terminal.
- Install brightnessctl
- Get a list of available devices. Type:
  `brightnessctl -l`
- Then set the brightness with:
  `sudo brightnessctl --device='{device name}' s {set ammount}`

My {device name} was `asus::kbd_backlight`

To turn off the backlighting I would type:
`sudo brightnessctl --device='asus::kbd_backlight' s 0`

I know this is not as convenient as a persistent setting in a GUI, but it is more powerful. You could create a shell script to turn the brightness up, down, on, or off.

Comment: Thank you for this. I dual boot Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 on an Asus ROG Strix. I am a bit of a Linux noob, but your solution worked for me. 

For other noobs, if you want to install brightnessctl:

`$ sudo apt update
    $ sudo apt install brightnessctl`

Answer (score 3):

To turn on keyboard LED backlighting in Ubuntu Linux 22.04 try this comnand in a terminal:

```
xset led on
```

or

```
xset led 3
```

and to turn off keyboard backlighting LEDs:

```
xset led off
```

If it works you can bind them to keyboard shortcuts in keyboard settings (eg. Scroll Lock and Ctrl-Scroll lock) or make desktop launchers to run them.

Comment: xset -led 3 and after xset led 3 this command not working on ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS. Is there any other command for turn on the external keyboard's backlight

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on my MacBookAir8,2 that is running dual boot Ubuntu 22.04.2:

The files needed to control the keyboard backlighting were in /sys/class/leds/apple::kbd_backlight/
[screenshot of the file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8hk6.png)

To change the keyboard backlight brightness to the maximum on the Terminal, type: `echo 512 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/apple::kbd_backlight/brightness` The max brightness file says the maximum brightness is 512. If you type the command with a 0 instead of 512, it turns the keyboard backlight off.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for weeks in keyboard drivers, using lots of things like `xkb`, `xmodmap`, and so on. But no one worked!

I have MSI KATANA GF66 and this worked for me perfectly and it will work for anyone if `openrgb` supports their keyboard backlight.

Follow these steps:

1. Install `openrgb` using these commands:
   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/openrgb -y`
   `sudo apt update`
   `sudo apt install openrgb`
2. Open `openrgb` app and set a color you like and save the profile named `on_color`
3. set the backlight off using the option of `off` in `openrgb` and save the profile as `off_color`
4. Add a custom keyboard shortcut in **Settings > Keyboard > View and Customize Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts** using `+` sign
5. Use a custom name like `openrgb backlight off` in name section.
   Use this command in the command section:
   `openrgb -p off_color`
   Use a favorite key combination like `Ctrl + Shift + Z`
6. Add another custom shortcut using `+` sign.
   Use a custom name like `openrgb backlight on` in name section.
   Use this command in the command section:
   `openrgb -p on_color`
   Use a favorite key combination like `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + Z`

from now on you can  turn on/off the keyboard backlight using these keyboard shortcuts. (and you can add more colors as many as you like)